# Derivation of Inequality in Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, proof-explanation

I've been reading through a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra and I am trying to understand how an inequality was derived. The actual proof is located here https://mathscholar.org/2018/09/simple-proofs-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra/.

In the proof, it's given that
$$p(z)=p_0+p_1z+p_2z^2+\cdots +p_nz^n$$
where the coefficients $p_i$ are complex numbers with neither $p_0$ nor $p_n$ equal to zero.

The line I'm confused about is this...

> **First note that for large 
>   $z$
>   , say 
>   $|
> z
> |
> >
> 2
> \max_
> i
> \left|
> \large{
> \frac{p_i}{p_n}
> }
> \right|$, the 
>   $z^
> n$
>    term of 
>   $p
> (
> z
> )$
>    is greater in absolute value than the sum of all the other terms.**

How was the inequality derived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $|z| > 2\max_i\left|{\large{\frac{p_i}{p_n}}}\right|$.

In particular, using $i=n$, we get $|z| > 2$, hence $2(|z|-1) > |z|$.

Letting $r=\max_i |p_i|$, we have $|z| > {\Large{\frac{2r}{|p_n|}}}$, hence
\begin{align*}
&\left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}p_iz^i\right|\\[4pt]
\le\;&\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|p_iz^i|\\[4pt]
=\;&\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|p_i||z|^i\\[4pt]
\le\;&r\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|z|^i\\[4pt]
=\;&r\left(\frac{|z|^n-1}{|z|-1}\right)\\[4pt]
=\;&2r\left(\frac{|z|^n-1}{2(|z|-1)}\right)\\[4pt]
 < \;&2r\left(\frac{|z|^n}{|z|}\right)\\[4pt]
=\;&2r|z|^{n-1}\\[4pt]
=\;&|p_n|\cdot \frac{2r}{|p_n|}\cdot |z|^{n-1}\\[4pt]
 < \;&|p_n|\cdot |z|\cdot |z|^{n-1}\\[4pt]
=\;&|p_nz^n|\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the response. This makes sense. Its hard for me to wrap my head around how you would make some of the chosen steps without first knowing that z should be greater than 2maxi|pi/pn|.

Comment: Actually, you can get all the way down to the expression two lines before the end with the only assumption on $|z|$  being $|z| > 2$. Then see how that compares with $|p_n z^n|$ in order to get the final bound on $z$.